# Call Oracle function with a cursor IN/OUT

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to make a simple call to a function(Test2) which takes a cursor, and returns a cursor.

I am stuck with the error:
Error(23,17): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '**TEST2**'

What is wrong with my function call?

```
v_resp := TEST2(v_req);
```

Here is my test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TRANS_OBJ AS OBJECT (TRANSNO CHAR(8));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TRANS_OBJ_TAB AS TABLE OF TRANS_OBJ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST2 (v_rc IN SYS_REFCURSOR) RETURN TRANS_OBJ_TAB
IS
  v_resp TRANS_OBJ_TAB := TRANS_OBJ_TAB();

  BEGIN 
    v_resp.extend;
    v_resp(1) := TRANS_OBJ('222222');
    RETURN v_resp; 
  END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST1 RETURN TRANS_OBJ_TAB
IS
  TRANSNO   CHAR(8);
  v_cnt number := 0;
  v_req TRANS_OBJ_TAB := TRANS_OBJ_TAB();
  v_resp TRANS_OBJ_TAB := TRANS_OBJ_TAB();
  --v_resp sys_refcursor;      

  CURSOR v_rc IS SELECT '1111' AS TRANSNO FROM DUAL;

  BEGIN
      OPEN v_rc;

      LOOP
        fetch v_rc into TRANSNO;
        EXIT WHEN v_rc%NOTFOUND;

        v_req.extend;
        v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
        v_req(v_cnt)  := TRANS_OBJ(TRANSNO);
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE v_rc;
      v_resp := TEST2(v_req);
      RETURN v_resp;
    END;
/
DROP TYPE TRANS_OBJ_TAB;
DROP TYPE TRANS_OBJ;
DROP FUNCTION TEST1;
DROP FUNCTION TEST2;
```

Comment: v_req isn't sys_refcursor. (v_req TRANS_OBJ_TAB)

Answer (score 1):

First you are not returning a CURSOR from TEST2 function as you says (try `return sys_refcursor`).
On the other hand v_req is not an sys_refcursor, besides v_resp can't contains a cursor too. Review the types you are using.
Hope this help!!!